# Spring security: how to implement "two-step" authentication (oauth then form-based)?

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth

In my app, I have two different gateways for authentication that work separately pretty good:

1. OAuth 1.0 ([service-to-service](http://oauthbible.com/#oauth-10a-one-legged)) which gives ROLE_OAUTH to the
   user; Here I know nothing about a user and have only some context information about service it uses inside Principal object;
2. Standard form-based authentication that gives ROLE_USER to the
   user; Here I have full information about my user but no context information about service it uses inside Principal object;

Now I want to implement two-step authentication: 1) OAuth then form-based.

The complexity is that **I do not want to lose context-specific information stored in the Principal after step 1 (OAuth)**; I just want to add some new user-specific information after the completion of form-based authentication to the security context as well as a new role ROLE_USER, all in the same authentication session.

Is it possible to implement smoothly? How can I extract already existing Principal info during second step (form-based authentication) and add it to the new Principal?

Is there any kind of "template solution" without re-inventing the wheel?

**My current straightforward solution would be:**

1. I have authenticated user with role ROLE_OAUTH and opened
   authentication session;
2. Create a separate path for 2-d step like */oauth/login*;
3. After user enters his credentials, I process them outside the
   security chain in a controller manually checking the credentials;
4. If successful, manually update the security context not loosing
   the authentication session, then redirect user to the requested protected by 
   ROLE_USER resource;

But I do not like it, it seems lame since I have to manually process second security request..

How can I implement this correctly in Spring-ish way? Thank you.

**P.S.** I have to use Oauth 1.0 for legacy reasons, cannot upgrade it to v.2 or any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is how I managed to fulfill this task.

1. I have an authenticated user (actually service) with role ROLE_OAUTH
   and opened authentication session and some **crucial information** about the context
   kept in the session that was hard-wired into OAuth request;
2. Now when trying to access a protected resource that demands another role, say ROLE_USER, Spring gives me [AccessDeniedException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDeniedException.html) and sends 403 forbidden response (see [AccessDeniedHandlerImpl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.html)), kindly suggesting to override the default behavior if needed in a custom AccessDeniedHandler. Here is the code sample:

---

```
   public class OAuthAwareAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
   private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(OAuthAwareAccessDeniedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (oauthSecurityUtils.isUserWithOnlyOAuthRole(auth)) {
            LOG.debug("Prohibited to authorize OAuth user trying to access protected resource.., redirected to /login");
            // Remember the request pathway
            RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
            requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
            return;
        }
        LOG.debug("Ordinary redirection to /accessDenied URL..");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/accessDenied");
    }
}
```

3. Now we need to add this new handler to the configuration:

---

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // all the config
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAwareAccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

4. After this step the default [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) would process the input by creating another Authentication object with entered credentials, the default behavior just loses the existing information wired into previous OAuth Authentication object. So we need to override this default behavior by extending this class, like this, fnd adding this filter before the standard UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

---

```
public class OAuthAwareUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LTIAwareUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    Authentication previousAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    // Check for OAuth authentication in place
    if (oauthSecurityUtils.isUserWithOnlyOAuthRole(previousAuth)) {
        LOG.debug("OAuth authentication exists, try to authenticate with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in the usual way");
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        Authentication authentication = null;
        try {// Attempt to authenticate with standard UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
            authentication = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            // If fails by throwing an exception, catch it in unsuccessfulAuthentication() method
            LOG.debug("Failed to upgrade authentication with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(previousAuth);
            throw e;
        }
        LOG.debug("Obtained a valid authentication with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter");
        Principal newPrincipal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        // Here extract all needed information about roles and domain-specific info
        Principal rememberedPrincipal = previousAuth.getPrincipal();
       // Then enrich this remembered principal with the new information and return it
        LOG.debug("Created an updated authentication for user");
        return newAuth;
    }
    LOG.debug("No OAuth authentication exists, try to authenticate with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in the usual way");
    return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    Authentication previousAuth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (oauthSecurityUtils.isUserWithOnlyOAuthRole(previousAuth)) {
        LOG.debug("unsuccessfulAuthentication upgrade for OAuth user, previous authentication :: "+ previousAuth);
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        LOG.debug("fallback to previous authentication");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(previousAuth);
    } else {
        LOG.debug("unsuccessfulAuthentication for a non-OAuth user with UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter");
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    }
}
```

}

The only thing left is to add this filter before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and apply it only to the given endpoint:

---

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(oauthAwareUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // here come ant rules
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(oauthAwareAccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

That's it. This example is tested to be workable. Maybe some side-effects will be found afterwards, not sure. Also I'm sure it could be done in a more refined way, but I'll go with this code for now.